# How to add condition in solidity in auction contract one address can bid only one time

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, mapping, auctions

```
 function bid(bytes32 _blindedBid)
        public
        payable
        onlyBefore(biddingEnd)
    {
        // If the bid is not higher, send the money back
        // (the failing require will revert all changes in this function execution including it having received the money).
        require(msg.value >= minBid, "Your bid is lower then minimum bidding amount. Try bidding higher!");
        
        bids[msg.sender].push(Bid({
            blindedBid: _blindedBid,
            deposit: msg.value
        }));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, for instance, have a mapping of addresses having already placed a bid and a require based on it

```
mapping(address=>bool) alreadyBid;
```

then `require(!alreadyBid[msg.sender], "max bid reachded");`

Comment: I make a contract in which i am making a multiple auction using singal contract and bidders can bid. But i want to add functionality when bidder place a bid he can selet auction from multiple auctions. IS there any solution?